# winform webbrowser display pdf in same window

Tags: winforms, pdf, browser, controls

I have a simple question which expects a simple answer! :-)

In a visual basic .NET winform I drop a WebBrowser control

Within the form's load event script I have this:
WebBrowser1.navigate("http://www.whateverWebsite.com/WhateverDocument.pdf")

Now the issue is that **the webbrowser actually launches an Adobe reader new window** with the PDF document, and that window is NOT part of my application.
In my application the WebBrowser control says: Navigation Cancelled!!!!

What I want is the pdf file displayed within the actual WebBrowser control.

Any fix greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have control over what kind of PDF view software the users will install in their own machines? PDF viewers are free to decide whether cancel the navigation and show in its own window, or show the file in-place, or to change the storage method of settings

Comment: I am doing the same, and getting the same issue. By any chance do you remember, how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a setting in Adobe reader? Look for Display PDF in browser in settings.

Comment: I have no idea, but since my users are running my own application, I don't want them to have tof fiddle with IE browser options! That wouldn't look very "profesional", would it?

Comment: But that's the way. And I meant Adobe settings not IE settings. Maybe they set it to not display pdf in web browser specifically?

Comment: So how do you reach Adobe Settings??? Apparently when you open Adobe Reader there are no Options available!

Comment: I'm using Foxit Reader. But found this http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-pdf-from-opening-in-web-browser-ie-firefox-opera-safari/

Comment: +1 vote for your help! I could actually change ther way the PDF opens. But that doesn't solve my problem when a user has the wrong behavior on his own computer! How can I change this programmatically?

Comment: I suggest going to adobe forums. But I wouldn't expect to be able to change this programmatically.